# Is there a viewDidAppear for Tabhost with fragments? Want to run code when user comes back to the tab

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-studio

Is there a way to run code when you go to a tab? For example you go to the second tab (runs code) and then leave it. You go back to the second tab (runs code). I'm porting my iOS app to android and in Xcode you'd just put the code in viewdidappear, is there something similar in Android?

How my fragment looks like:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class ReportFragment extends Fragment {

private View mRootView;

// create boolean for fetching data
private boolean isViewShownReport = false;

@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    if (getView() != null) {
        isViewShownReport = true;
        // fetchdata() contains logic to show data when page is selected mostly asynctask to fill the data
        //fetchData();
    } else {
        isViewShownReport = false;
    }
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (mRootView == null){
        Log.e("666","ReportFragment");
        mRootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.report_fragment,container,false);
    }
    ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) mRootView.getParent();
    if (parent != null){
        parent.removeView(mRootView);
    }

    if (!isViewShownReport) {
        //fetchData();// or anything that you want to execute after tab selection

        //System.out.println("Hello!")
        Log.d("myTag", "ReportFragment");
    }

    return mRootView;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// create boolean for fetching data
private boolean isViewShown = false;

@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    if (getView() != null) {
        isViewShown = true;
        // fetchdata() contains logic to show data when page is selected mostly asynctask to fill the data
        fetchData();
    } else {
        isViewShown = false;
    }
} 


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_layout, container, false);

   // view initialization steps.......

   if (!isViewShown) {
        fetchData();// or anything that you want to execute after tab selection
   } 
   // do other stuff
}
```

Comment: nvm, how do i get it to work on multiple tabs? doesn't work when i put it in multiple tabs

Comment: seems like it only works when there are 2 tabs aswell. for example if there are 4 tabs, and i put it in the second tab, if i goto the second tab then 4th then third it will execute the code while on the third.

Comment: I edited my post so you can see what my fragment looks like